# Can I understand that "as long as" is 1st Conditional and "If only" is 2nd or 3rd Conditional?

Tags: phrases

When I think about this sentence "As long as you study English, you can improve your English", it means "If you study English, you can improve your English", and it is 1st Conditional.

When I think about this sentence "If only I could speak English", it means "I wish I could speak English", and it is 2nd Conditional.

Are there cases that "as long as" is used as 2nd Conditional and "If only" is used as 1st Conditional?

Comment: _If only_ is counterfactual, which is what I think TEFL teachers mean by "2nd/3rd conditional". _As long as_ is not counterfactual, which I think they mean by "1st conditional".

Comment: The categorization of conditionals is not something done by most native speakers. It's a generalization that is often incomplete or confusing (mostly only provided by ESL teachers and texts), and it's certainly not a strict rule. It serves only as a guide post. Don't ask about conditionals; ask about what you really mean.